# Launch OS X Application Programmatically

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-yosemite

How do I programmatically open an OS X app (.app) that is contained within the app I am building?

Comment: You could do a system terminal call using "open /path/to/file.app"

Comment: What would the path be if the app I want to open is contained in the current app's bundle?

Comment: you could try `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myapp.app"]; system([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"open %@", path] UTF8String])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preferred way of doing this on OS X is through the `NSWorkspace` class, which provides a couple of methods to launch applications. One of them, [`launchApplicationAtURL:options:configuration:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/launchApplicationAtURL:options:configuration:error:) allows you to specify a file URL to the application to launch. In addition of not having sandbox problems like the `system()` and Apple Event solution, it also gives you an easy way to manipulate how the application should be launched, eg. you can specify environment variables to be passed to the application.

Answer (score 2):

**Following Code snippet is used to launch an app programmatically:**

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
path = [path stringByAppendingString:@"/MyApp.app"]; // App Path
NSWorkspace *ws=[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
[ws launchApplicationAtURL:url
                           options:NSWorkspaceLaunchWithoutActivation
                     configuration:nil
                             error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Apple Script.

```
NSDictionary* errorDict;
NSAppleEventDescriptor* returnDescriptor = NULL;

NSAppleScript* scriptObject;
scriptObject = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"try\n
run application \"Macintosh HD:Applications:_Sandbox-AppleScript0.app\"\n
on error number -609 # 'Connection is invalid' error that is spuriously reported # simply ignore\n
end try"];

if (returnDescriptor != NULL) {
     // successful execution
     if (kAENullEvent != [returnDescriptor descriptorType]) {
         // script returned an AppleScript result
         if (cAEList == [returnDescriptor descriptorType]) {
             // result is a list of other descriptors
         }
         else {
              // coerce the result to the appropriate ObjC type
         }
    }
}
```